# java.lang.CharSequence as a member of a Java class is not type-checked as expected

Tags: java, kotlin

The following code is rejected by the Kotlin compiler (rightfully so):

```kotlin
// main.kt
class KotlinFoo(val bar: java.lang.CharSequence)

fun test(foo: KotlinFoo) {
    println(foo.bar == "hi")
}
```

Error:

```
Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'CharSequence' and 'String'
```

The following, however, is accepted without complaints:

```java
// JavaFoo.java
public class JavaFoo {
    public java.lang.CharSequence bar;
}
```

```kotlin
// main2.kt
fun test(foo: JavaFoo) {
    println(foo.bar == "hi")
}
```

I would have expected it to generate the same error.

Is this compiler behavior intended?

Comment: I think this is intended. It could be that the compiler is designed to only port JVM types when they are from Java source code, because you are not supposed to use `java.lang.CharSequence` in Kotlin anyway. And I don't know what _else_ could be intended. Any other behaviour doesn't seem reasonable. That said, there is no sources for my claim, as the Kotlin/JVM spec doesn't exist yet.

Comment: By the way, your expected behaviour is would make calling Java code from Kotlin _super_ painful. Trying to use anything from Java would make your Kotlin code look like Java. Have you seen [this page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html)? The "mapped types" section there _might_ convince you that this is intended. :)

Comment: `class KotlinFoo(val bar: CharSequence)` works too.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `kotlin.String` `"hi"` is guaranteed to be not `java.lang.CharSequence` but `kotlin.CharSequence`. These classes have different subtyping hierarchies.

So, you should use `kotlin.CharSequence` in all cases, because on JVM it is mapped to `java.lang.CharSequence` by the ecompiler anyway.

However, there is a hack if you really want to use Java types in Kotlin—you can cast Kotlin's char sequences to Java ones:

```kotlin
    val s: java.lang.CharSequence = "42" as java.lang.CharSequence
    println(s == "42" as java.lang.CharSequence)
```

Comment: Thanks. It's not that I *want* to use Java types in Kotlin, they are coming from a library. :)

Comment: @TobiasHermann fortunately, Kotlin properly handles types from Java.

Comment: By the way, some low-level synchronization code compels the casting of Kotlin values to `java.lang.Object` because `kotlin.Any` lacks `wait` and `notify`.